# update attribute of model only through defined method instead of default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model named "MyModel" and it has attribute named "status".
I could update this attribute like this:
  model.status = "new"
  model.save!

However, I override this update method with my own model method "update_status". Any update through the default updating will be reject unless it uses "update_status"

Comment: what problem do you have?  and how would you like to solve it?  please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

What you can certainly do is track the changed attributes, and filter only those you want to allow to be updatable in before_update callback. In your `update_status` method you could use assignment through `update_column` which does not trigger callbacks.

```
  before_update :prevent_status_update

  private
  def prevent_status_update
    return true unless self.changed.includes? 'status'
    self.errors.add_to_base "Cannot update a #{ self.to_s }"
    false
  end
```